# Adding rules to existing jQuery form processing script

Tags: jquery, json, forms, validation, jquery-validate

I am working on a client site that has the following existing script:

```
/** Event Registration **/
var isSubmitingForm = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#eventRegForm").validate({
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            $("#eventRegForm span.input-text-error").removeClass("input-text-error");
            $("#eventRegForm div.textarea-error").removeClass("textarea-error");
        },
        submitHandler: function(form, validator) {
            $("#eventRegForm span.input-text-error").removeClass("input-text-error");
            $("#eventRegForm div.textarea-error").removeClass("textarea-error");
            var formData = "ServerProcess=true&FriendlyName=Event Registration&" + $("#eventRegForm").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/forms/generic",
                data: formData,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    if(!isSubmitingForm) {
                        isSubmitingForm = true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                    $("#eventRegForm").prepend("<div class='loading'>Loading...<div>");
                },
                success: function (responseText) {
                    $("#eventRegForm").clearForm();
                    isSubmitingForm = false;
                    $("#eventRegForm div.loading").fadeOut(function() {
                        if($("#eventRegForm div.message").get(0)) {
                            $("#eventRegForm div.message").remove()
                        }
                        $("#eventRegForm").before("<div class='message message-success'><h5>Thank you for taking the time to complete this form.</h5>Your submission was sent.</div>");
                        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                        $('form#eventRegForm').fadeOut();
                    });
                },
                error: function (responseText) {
                    $("#eventRegForm").clearForm();
                    isSubmitingForm = false;
                    $("#eventRegForm div.loading").fadeOut(function() {
                        if($("#eventRegForm div.message").get(0)) {
                            $("#eventRegForm div.message").remove()
                        }
                        $("#eventRegForm div.line:eq(0)").before("<div class='message message-error'><h5>Error!</h5>An error has ocurred. Please try again.</div>");
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        rules: {
            eventRegFormName: {
                required: true
            },
            eventRegFormLastName: {
                required: true
            },
            eventRegFormEmail: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {


        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            element.parent().addClass("input-text-error");
            element.parent().addClass("textarea-error");
        },
        onsubmit: true,
        onkeyup: false,
        onfocusout: false
    });

    $("#eventRegForm a.button").click(function () {
        $("#eventRegForm").submit();
    });
});
```

I cannot edit existing scripts on a live site, but I can add new jQuery in an include file that will load on the page. What is needed here is I am inserting more options to a `<select>` in the form. With these new options, the select field itself is now required; the first default option will be a blank/null value.

In my new jQuery code, which will run after the script file above, how to add more rules, if it's even possible? The `<select>` that needs to be required has an ID of eventRegFormEventTitle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [jQuery Validation documentation for rules](http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/#-rules()).

`$('#eventRegFormEventTitle').rules('add',{required:true});`